# Angularjs rootscope not updating ngClass when route change

Tags: angularjs, routes, angularjs-scope, ng-class, rootscope

On `$routeChangeStart` I like to apply `of-h` class and on `$routeChangeSuccess` either I like remove `of-h` class or change it to `of-v` class. Now only `of-h` class get applied.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-outer" ng-class="addClassOnRouteChange">
  <div class="container" ng-view autoscroll="true" ng-class="fadeNgView">
    <!-- Views will be rendered here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'myApp.controllers'])

  .run(['$window', '$location','$rootScope', function ($window, $location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.fadeNgView = '';

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
      //event button item list to move forward
      $rootScope.next = function() {
        console.log('start');
        $rootScope.fadeNgView = 'fade-ng-view';
        $rootScope.addClassOnRouteChange = 'of-h';
      }
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
      $rootScope.addClassOnRouteChange = 'of-v';
    });
  }]);
```

Comment: have you tried with $rootScope.$apply??

Comment: You can use $scope because the bindings are happening outside the scope of ng-veiw

Comment: I just did this as you mentioned `$rootScope.$apply.addClassOnRouteChange = 'of-v'` but no luck :(

Comment: @vivz I am getting error when $scope injected, I already have a ticket for that issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/44542478/1292050

Comment: No I meant this, $rootScope.$apply(function(){$rootScope.addClassOnRouteChang‌​e = 'of-h';});

Comment: @SangwinGawande I would like to mark your solution as selected answer because it works :)

Comment: Glad I could Help, Mark it correct, I have answered it below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
$rootScope.$apply(function(){
    $rootScope.addClassOnRouteChang‌​‌​e = 'of-h';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
  //event button item list to move forward
  $rootScope.addClassOnRouteChange = true;
  $rootScope.next = function() {
    console.log('start');
    $rootScope.fadeNgView = 'fade-ng-view';
    $rootScope.addClassOnRouteChange = true;
  }
});

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
  $rootScope.addClassOnRouteChange = false;
});
```

Now change `ng-class` code to

```
ng-class="{addClassOnRouteChange?'of-h':'of-v'}"
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried your solution, I am getting error. Hence @Sangwin's soltuion that's mentioned in the comment. `angular.js:10072 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$parse/syntax?p0=%3F&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=25&p3=%7B"<div class="container-slides" ng-class="{ ofHiddenOnRouteChange ? 'of-h':'of-v' }">"fHiddenOnRouteChange%20%3F%20'of-h'%3A'of-v'%20%7D&p4=%3F%20'of-h'%3A'of-v'%20%7D`