# Getting Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] when $scope injected

Tags: angularjs

When I try to add `$scope` in the below give code I am getting error

```
angular.module('starter', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'myApp.controllers'])
  .run(['$window', '$location', '$rootScope', '$scope', function ($window, $location, $rootScope, $scope) {}]);
```

**Error:**

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't inject `$scope` to the run component. alternatively, you have to use the `$rootScope`.Because top-level scope is rootScope and all child scope is inherit from it

```
angular.module('starter', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'myApp.controllers'])
  .run(['$window', '$location', '$rootScope', function ($window, $location, $rootScope) {

}]);
```